# pip3 install firebase-admin fails at Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: raspberry-pi, firebase-admin, debian-buster

I'm trying to install firebase-admin on a Raspberry Pi. I have 3 cards with fresh Debian 10 (buster) (i.e. fully updated/upgraded), and tried 3 different ways to get firebase-admin to install (I know it can be done since I did it on another Raspberry Pi, but did so many things before I finally got it to install, that I can't reproduce what I did!). So in each attempt to install firebase-admin, I get the "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Here is what I did on 2 fresh cards in the RPi:

1. export PATH="/home/pi/.local/bin:$PATH"
2. python3 -m pip install google-cloud-storage  (successful)
3. python3 -m pip install firebase (successful)
4. python3 -m pip install firebase_admin  ---> fails with error shown above

I then tried sudo in front of the python3 commands above, with the same result.  Finally, on one of the non-sudo cards, I did a "python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel" (successful), and then repeated step 4 above with the same result (i.e. python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1).

I am desperate (and doing something really basic and stupid?) .... any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks  (I have tried all suggestions in questions similar to this one, without success).

Answer (score 1):

Using a raspberry-pi zero W, almost identical problem. firebase works fine, `firebase_admin` fails with:

> python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.  │ exit code: 1

It seems to work if you install the firebase admin package with an older version of grpcio. This is the command I used.

```
pip install firebase-admin "grpcio <= 1.40.0"
```

I don't know if it's necessary, but I had that specific version of `grpcio` already installed manually, from a previous attempt to fix the issue:

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir  --force-reinstall -Iv grpcio==1.40.0
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Andrei,  Thanks for the response.  I had given up and went to ESP32, but prefer RPi and will try your suggestion (however, I can't access my RPi stuff for another month - I will get back to you and other readers once I have tried it.  Thanks !